# Cross browser disable the user select (Ctrl + A)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, event-handling

By default the user can drag and select the screen item  / press CTRL + A ,all the item will be turn blue and blur (selected). However, is there any way to block this event? Thanks

Are there any simple way just like adding some restriction in browser or adding some attribute in body tag can solve the problem?

Comment: why u need this ? if user turn off the javascript then ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css rule to disable text selection highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
user-select:none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
```

Add Following `user-select` property to that element which you do not want to turn blue. Adding it to body will turn `selectable` or `editable` elements to not be `selectable` or `editable`. So, it is recommended to use it on specific elements e.g.

```
div, image, iframe {
    user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

Or You can See More on:

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/user-select)

Comment: This does not prevent selection with Ctrl+A in Firefox

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using jquery

```
$(function(){   
$(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {        
    if (objEvent.ctrlKey) {          
        if (objEvent.keyCode == 65) {                         
            objEvent.disableTextSelect();
            return false;
        }            
    }        
});
});
```

Hope it works,this code disable ctrl+a on browser